# Defining jQuery variable from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery search script that uses tabs for the user to define which search type they want to use. When a user searches, a URL is created which is something like #**type**/***query***/. I need to somehow define the query terms in my `window.location.hash.replace` so I am just left with the search type from the URL. How can I go about changing the **QUERYGOESHERE** in my example below to the query the user has made? I hope people can understand my question.

My jQuery Script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^=type_]').click(function () {
        type = this.id.replace('type_', '');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_' + type).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        url = window.location.hash.replace('#', '').replace('/QUERYGOESHERE/', '');
        $('#type_' + url).click();
    } else {
        $('#type_search').click();
    }
    $('#query').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        var url = '/' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        window.location.hash = '' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        document.title = $(this).val() + ' - My Search Script';
        $('#results').show();
        if (query == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search Script';
            $('#results').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (results) {
                $('#results').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
    var textlength = $('#query').val().length;
    if (textlength <= 0) {
        $('#query').focus();
    } else {
        $('#query').blur();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var full = window.location.hash.replace('#', '')
var queryType = full.substring(0,full.indexOf("/"))
var query = full.replace(queryType, '');
```

EDIT: Updated code

```
if (window.location.hash != "") { 
  var full = window.location.hash.replace('#', ''); 
  var queryType = full.substring(0,full.indexOf("/")); 
  console.log('#type_' + queryType); 
  $('#type_' + queryType).click(); 
}
```

Comment: one possibility is it may be having trouble with the trailing /. I'll do a little testing on it.

Comment: @CallumWhyte let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1713/discussion-between-joseph-and-callum-whyte)

Comment: could you tell me an example of what url should be in this part? $('#type_' + url).click();